# Convert unordered list into array for saving to localstorage

Tags: javascript, arrays, html-lists

I have an unordered list which I can append li elements onto. I want to know how to convert the list into something that can be stored and remade through localstorage? I believe this entails the conversion of the list into an array and then appending it back to the ul...

Here is the code I'm working with (currently I'm just having an `alert()` because I'm at a loss on how to append the stored data).

```js
function A() {
  var list = document.getElementById("list").innerHTML;
  localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(list));
}

function B() {
  var saved = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("list"));
  alert(saved);
}

function addLi() {
  var ul = document.getElementById("list");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Addition to list."));
  ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="A()">A()</button>
<button onclick="B()">B()</button>
<button onclick="addLi()">addLi()</button>

<div id="listCover">
  <ul id="list">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @marekful - Note the OP is *using* `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing, using `.innerHTML`, should work just fine. Since that's a string, no need for `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`.

Alternately, you could loop through the `li` elements and add their contents to an array, then store the array (with `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`, since web storage only stores strings).

That latter option looks something like this:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll("#list li");
var array = Array.prototype.map.call(items, function(item) {
    return item.textContent;
});
localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(array));
```

and

```
var saved = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("list")) || [];
saved.forEach(addLi);
```

...if we modify `addLi` to accept the text to add:

```
function addLi(text) {
    var ul = document.getElementById("list");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
    ul.appendChild(li);
}
```